# Swing Timer issue - stop Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have been trying to stop the timer and solve this for days now, unfortunately no luck, hope someone will be able to help.

The idea is to use the timer to click a button which increases the value in the text field so I have the timer in the start button and I wish to stop it in the stop button.

That's the code I have behind my  start button:

```
private void btStartTimerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

        javax.swing.Timer tm = new javax.swing.Timer(100, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                btAddOneActionPerformed(evt);
               }
        });
tm.start();

 private void btStopTimerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

}
```

Comment: The solution to this is in keeping a reference to the `Timer` object created.  Keeping a reference to an object instance is OOP 1010, something you should sort out before attempting GUIs.

Comment: well that's not much help, thank you....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this is in keeping a reference to the `Timer` object that is created.  For more info. see [The Java™ Tutorials - Classes and Objects: Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html).